# Having Issue on Bootstrap Popover Closing Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/v7FWZUAkIn) and let me know why I am not able to pop over the popover on First click after closing the popover through the added close button?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : true,
        title : 'User Info <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>',
        content : '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="../images/avatar-tiny.jpg" class="media-object" alt="Sample Image"></a><div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading">Jhon Carter</h4><p>Excellent Bootstrap popover! I really love it.</p></div></div>'
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".popover .close" , function(){
        $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
    });
});
```

as you can see the popover is available every time on clicking on `<button>Click Me</button` but when I close it by `x` (close) button it is not popping up at first try! but it works in second click!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that is happening - it appears to be a bug. However, you can work around it by simply triggering the popover button's click event when the user clicks the close button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : true,
        title : 'User Info <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>',
        content : '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="../images/avatar-tiny.jpg" class="media-object" alt="Sample Image"></a><div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading">Jhon Carter</h4><p>Excellent Bootstrap popover! I really love it.</p></div></div>'
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
      var popup = $(this);
      $(this).parent().find("div.popover .close").click(function() {
        popup.click();
      });
    });
});
```

[Demo Here](http://www.bootply.com/5TmuuzAa5o)