# Bootstrap Popover x button works, but title disappears after first time clicked

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I basically used the instructions found in this question: [stack-overflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110961/having-issue-on-bootstrap-popover-closing-button)

However, a strange thing happens. After I click the x, the title disappears completely and never reappears until I reload the page.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
        var popup = $(this);
        $(this).parent().find("div.popover .close").click(function() {
            popup.click();
        });
    });
});
```

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a  class="btn btn-lg btn-default extra" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" title="Modify Formulary <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>" data-placement="left"  data-content='SOME CONTENT  '><i class="menu-icon fa fa-edit"></i></a> 
</div>
```

There is also a little css:

```
    .popover-title .close{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3px;
}
```

I have bootstrap and jquery included both css and js and I believe latest versions.

Here is the codepen example: [click](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvLeYR)

Comment: Can you make a codepen or jsFiddle of the issue?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvLeYR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of Bootstrap. For this to work correctly you need Bootstrap v. 3.3.5. Here is the working codepen: http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/XborQB

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3c1npLob/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,  
    title: 'Modify Formulary <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>',
    content: 'SOME CONTENT  ',
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    var popup = $(this);
    $(this).parent().find("div.popover .close").click(function() {
      popup.click();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ended up using this. I also took cavan flynn's suggestion and moved to the newer version of bootstrap. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @DanSafee should've accepted @CananFlynn 's answer - he found the problem. I recreated the case from the ground up, because I never noticed you're using older `js` file.

Comment: Took your advice. That did appear to be the only problem.